# Create flash executable that calls external dll functions

Tags: flash, winapi, dll

Is it possible to create an executable from flash that is able to call functions in an external dll (such as the windows API for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not with Adobe tools. You must use one of programs taht creates exe from swf file.

Comment: You also can create your own application (in language you know) having Flash Player plug-in and call your application's methods by fscommands or external interface.